# how to apply color from color palette to an element in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a color palette from which the user will be selecting a particular color and that color should apply to certain element. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the color code of the chosen color and apply it to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use devextreme color palette.

```
npm install devextreme  
npm install devextreme-angular
```

Then use the below code wherever you want to use color palette.

```
<dx-color-box
     [(value)]="color"
     [editAlphaChannel]="true">
</dx-color-box>
```

Then apply the color to an element:

```
 <div [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">

 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't want to use devrexreme. Already i have few colors from that only user need to select.

Comment: Then you can bind that value to ngStyle as shown in the last code.

Comment: I have done with javascript's getElementById method. Anyway Thank you Sagar Chaudhary

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install the whole devextreme module for just a color picker.
You just need to use HTML input tag.

```
<input type="color" [(ngModel)]="inputColor" name="inputColor">
```

And then use

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color': inputColor}">
Your Element
</div>
```

Comment: I have just provided him with an alternative . If he is using charts or grid ,he can use devextreme.

Answer (score 0):

In you `component.html` use `ngStyle`

```
<h1 [ngStyle]="{'color':yourColorVariable}">
You picked {{ yourColorVariable }}!
</h1>
```